# Amazon Auto Scale is ping ponging since the health checks fail

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have my Auto Scaling Group configured like so:
[image]
[image]

My Load balancer, when it registers an instance, fails since the health check fails while the instance is still loading.
[image]

For what it's worth, my health check is as follows:
[image]

I've added the "web-master" instance myself, not part of the auto scale, since what normally happens is that the registering instance fails to add itself to the load balancer, terminates and a new one pops up. This happens countless times until I manually intervene. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to delay the ELB Health check or at least have it wait till the instance is fully registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance shouldn't register until its passed its availability tests. Could it be that its your applications spin up time that's the issue, not the instance.

I guess my question is, is your application set up on the port your pinging? I have a lightweight  'healthcheck' app in iis for heathchecks to get around the 'ping pong' effect.